# Custom CSV Parser for 3 types

Tags: java, parsing, csv

Looking for a Custom CSV Parser for: 3 types: Int, String, Null

```
class CustomType{
    String s;
    int val;

    public CustomType(String s){
        this.s = s;
        val = -1;
    }

    public CustomType(int v){
        val = v;
        s = null;
    }
}
```

Given a string, parse it and return a list of a custom Type:

Example of String Inputs:

```
"X", 10,  = ["X", 10, null]
, = [null, null]
"Hi, You", 10, 20, = ["Hi, You", 10, 20, null]
"Hi "" You" = ["Hi " You"]
```

Notice for the last case, when you have 2 quotes in a row, one is escaped and only 1 appears in the answer.

Comment: So what did you try up to now?

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/csv